# Selenium IDE browser plugin 3.1.0

Tags: python, selenium

I have installed the new (!) Selenium IDE  3.1.0 Firefox plugin, and I can't find any facilities to export the tests, to run them from Python driver.

What am I missing? Search on SO only returns suggestions for the legacy IDE, but not for the new web-browser plugin

Comment: Is there any other language (C# NUnit, Java JUnit, etc.) that you can export? Do you have all the requirements refereed here: (CTRL + F and search 3.1.0 : https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/  ?